# how to get stack trace at various points in kernel device driver code

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, stack, kernel, linux-device-driver

I have a device driver code in Linux. Its execution includes lot of functions and different flows of functions.

For debugging, i wanted to know stack at some points in code.

E.g. 
lets say, 
A calls B, B calls C, then in function C, at some line where i want to know stack, should print something like

A-->B-->C

Is it possible doing this?
Let me know your answers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no evidence of any research: http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Enabling_Stack_Dumping_in_Linux_Kernel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dump_stack()` function will be helpful.

sample usage is
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/sound/soc/codecs/tpa6130a2.c#L393